# Is there any way to enumerate childcontent from parent component before it renders?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

For some reason, I need to know all the child elements (their tags, at least) in a wrapping component. For example, I have a structure like this:

```
<ParentComponent>
    <ChildComponent1/>
    <div>...</div>
    <h1>...</h1>
    ChildComponent2>
</ParentComponent>
```

Of course, My "ParentComponent" has code like this:

```
<div>
    @ChildContent
</div>

@functions
{

    [Parameter]
    private RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    ......
}
```

For some trivial details that I wouldn't bother, I need to get a list of child elements' tags, that is, in this case:

```
["ChildComponent1", "div", "h1", "ChildComponent2"]
```

And **the list should be available before ParentComponent renders**, which means I couldn't make the Cascade thing work because all children will add itself to the list at their own lifecycle hooks when the ParentComponent's OnParameterSet method has completed, not mention that I have no idea how to drive a common "div" element to achieve that Cascade-Use-Case. I guess there may be some spark hidden behind RenderFragment class, but I couldn't dig it out.

So, the target is simple, but the way I am looking for is tough, could anyone give me some clue to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to enumerate childcontent from parent component
>   before it renders?

The ChildContent parameter is a delegate of type RenderFragment rendering a fragment of content. As far as I know, there is no way you can use to access its constituent parts. Hence, there is no way you can enumerate the ChildContent...

See also this: [Is it possible to get a list of RenderFragments when overriding BuildRenderTree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56453173/is-it-possible-to-get-a-list-of-renderfragments-when-overriding-buildrendertree)

Hope this helps...